# Using jquery ajax to post from view to controller and then redirect with post in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I need to do the following 
I have to post form data using jquery from my view:

```
form_for(HomeController remote => true) do |f|
 Order number: <%=f.text_field_tag :order_number, '1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h'%> 
 Amount: <%=f.text_field_tag :amount, 1233.53%>
```

to my controller where I calculate something:

```
def calculation
  calculations = "expression"
  format.json {render json: calculations, status: :created}
  respond_to format.json
end
```

and then post that data (calculations) using redirect to an external link:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function (){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('data'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "JSON"
        }).success(function(result){
            $.post('link/', $(result).serialize())
        })
    })
});
```

However, my browser returns We're sorry, but something went wrong and request results in internal server error. Can anyone see any obvious mistakes?
I believe the mistake is in my view because I have some more code that runs normally when I comment out the part I showed in this query.
Any suggestions?

Comment: no effort spend. SO is not a free coding service!

Comment: Edited. Sorry for unfinished query.

Comment: internal server error is just a generic message which means something went wrong and crashed the server code. Check your server's logs for the underlying error, hopefully that will give you a better clue. Also, which of your two ajax requests is the one that's failing? And are you sure your form isn't also posting back simultaneously? There's no `event.preventDefault()` or `return false;` inside your `submit` event handler to stop the default postback action.

Comment: I managed to do all I wanted, will put an answer in a little while here, however, my calculations render on screen if I put format.json {render json: hash_calculated, status: :created} or they download in a file if I put format.json {send_data hash_calculated}

I need to post these calculations to a certain URL, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

First: your responder should be:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :yourjsontemplate, status: :created, anothervar: :value}
end
```

Second: In your form_for, add html options like this:

```
<%= form_for(Object, html: {remote: true}) do %>
```

Finally, when you do a POST will receive a 'complete'. So, your submit function in JS should be:

```
.complete(function(result){
        $.post('link/', $(result).serialize())
    })
```

EDITED:

form_form use the Model object to create your form, it should be passed as a instance variable initialized in your "new" action inside the controller, like this:

```
def new
  @something = YourModel.new
end
```

Then, use that variable in form_for:

```
<%= form_for(@something, html: {remote: true}) do %>
or
<%= form_for(YourModel.new, html: {remote: true}) do %>
```

---

Additionally:

Another method to send data from controller to your ajax call is using send_data. So, you can replace the block inside of format.json with:

```
format.json {send_data calculations} # or whatever you want
```

I hope that helps you

Comment: I figured out that I had to add |format| part and added it, it still does not work. Next, I followed your instructions and added . complete instead of .success and it still does not work. 
In my form, do I have to add my controller name with action like 'ControllerName/action' or can I just specify my object name even though I am not saving it in my controller?

Comment: I should also add some information, I'm using rails 3.2.2 and ruby 2.2.7, do not judge me, I have to because I have to learn these versions to be able to maintain pages made in those versions.

Comment: I've edit my Answer explaining your first comment. see and tell me if it respond to your questions. here is the form_for documentation [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for)

Comment: Your edited comment helped, it explained to me a little bit closer as what exactly does and how, however, my app is still not working and is displaying internal server error, I cannot find a way to show more error options in my rubymine app. :sighs:

Comment: Started GET "/home/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-26 13:41:58 +0200
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (10.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms


This is all I get in my server development log, can you point me to what should I change to have more information in my log?
Down is my development.rb file

Comment: I managed to do all I wanted, will put an answer in a little while here, however, my calculations render on screen if I put format.json {render json: hash_calculated, status: :created} or they download in a file if I put format.json {send_data hash_calculated} I need to post these calculations to a certain URL, can anyone help?